# Cirrus Logic 5440 video driver

Tags: drivers, video, dependencies

how to install video drivers from CS5440 in 18.04?
I see package xserver-xorg-video-cirrus isnt avaliable in 18.04. It depends on xorg-video-abi-20 in 16.04
So how can i install this driver in 18.04 ?

Comment: Maybe some internals were changed since 16.04. Have you tried to boot live cd/usb of 18.04 on hardware with Cirrus?

Comment: I couldnt start  x on my server so there is no way to boot live cd